# Exception transferring site files via webdav

Tags: maven, web, maven-3

uploading a site file with site-deploy has not worked completely.   I  consistently get an exception half way in uploading web pages to site through web DAV.
through the process. why this issue comes?

> Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Error uploading site
>       at org.apache.maven.plugins.site.AbstractDeployMojo.push(AbstractDeployMojo.java:464)
>       at org.apache.maven.plugins.site.AbstractDeployMojo.deploy(AbstractDeployMojo.java:296)
>       at org.apache.maven.plugins.site.AbstractDeployMojo.deployTo(AbstractDeployMojo.java:257)
>       at org.apache.maven.plugins.site.AbstractDeployMojo.execute(AbstractDeployMojo.java:165)
>       at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
>       at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
>       ... 27 more
>   Caused by: org.apache.maven.wagon.TransferFailedException: Specified source file does not exist: /home/directfn/hudson/jobs/NGP_OMS_SONAR/workspace/target/site/apidocs/com/directfn/oms/core/messaging_protocol/api/beans/inquiry/DSTReportRequestBean.html
>       at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.webdav.WebDavWagon.put(WebDavWagon.java:318)
>       at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.webdav.WebDavWagon.putDirectory(WebDavWagon.java:555)
>       at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.webdav.WebDavWagon.putDirectory(WebDavWagon.java:549)
>
> ...
>   Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/directfn/hudson/jobs   api/beans/inquiry/DSTReportRequestBean.html (Too many open files)
>       at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
>       at java.io.FileInputStream.(FileInputStream.java:138)
>       at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.webdav.PutInputStream.(PutInputStream.java:45)

Comment: This seems to be a Hudson issue http://issues.hudson-ci.org/browse/HUDSON-3076

Comment: it was identified that is due to wrong version 1.0-beta-2 maven wagon-webdav . http://www.mkyong.com/maven/how-to-deploy-site-with-mvn-site-deploy-webdav-example/